# Python Pandas Upsert

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I have daily data pipelines that need read a file and write the data to a postgres database. Some of theses files may be a mix of new and old data.

My current process is to take the file and write it to Dataframe, dump the Dataframe to a staging table, than execute and upsert. This works, but I am potentially updating values that are exactly the same. I would have compare all the columns in a row to see if theres a new value, which seems like more trouble than its worth (some tables might have 30+ columns).

Is there a better or more optimal way to do this? I feel like the larger my table or source files get the more time this process will take. Here is some example code of my process:

```
def example_import(file_path, engine):
    '''
    ETL example
    '''

    df_demo = download_from_ftp(file_path)

    if df_demo.empty:
        return

    # some cleaning might happen here

    df_demo.to_sql(con = engine, name = 'tbl', schema = 'staging', if_exists = 'replace', index = False, method = 'multi')

    with open('/somefolder/upsert.sql') as fp:
        upsert = fp.read()

    result = engine.execute(upsert)
    print('Inserted/Updated {} Records From {}'.format(result.rowcount, file_path))
```

**Example Data**:

Current Table (in reality have many more columns)

[image: Current Table]

Incoming Data (mix of new and old. some old PK have new values)

[image]

Data After Upsert

[image]

**Upsert Example**

```
INSERT INTO public."tbl" ("colA",
                                 "colB",
                                 "colC",
                                 "colD",
                                 "colE",
                                 "colF",
                                 "colG",
                                 "colH",
                                 "colI",
                                 "colJ",
                                 "colK",
                                 "colL",
                                 "colM",
                                 "colN",
                                 "colO",
                                 "colP",
                                 "colQ",
                                 "colR",
                                 "colS",
                                 "colT",
                                 "colU",
                                 "colV"
SELECT "colA",
         "colB",
         "colC",
         "colD",
         "colE"::DATE,
         "colF",
         "colG"::DATE,
         "colH",
         "colI"::DATE,
         "colJ"::DATE,
         "colK",
         "colL",
         "colM",
         "colN",
         "colO",
         "colP",
         "colQ",
         "colR",
         "colS",
         "colT",
         "colU",
         "colV"
FROM staging."tbl"
ON CONFLICT ("colA") DO UPDATE 
    SET "colB" = excluded."colB",
         "colC" = excluded."colC",
         "colD" = excluded."colD",
         "colE" = excluded."colE",
         "colF" = excluded."colF",
         "colG" = excluded."colG",
         "colH" = excluded."colH",
         "colI" = excluded."colI",
         "colJ" = excluded."colJ",
         "colK" = excluded."colK",
         "colL" = excluded."colL",
         "colM" = excluded."colM",
         "colN" = excluded."colN",
         "colO" = excluded."colO",
         "colP" = excluded."colP",
         "colQ" = excluded."colQ",
         "colR" = excluded."colR",
         "colS" = excluded."colS",
         "colT" = excluded."colT",
         "colU" = excluded."colU",
         "colV" = excluded."colV"
```

Comment: you can use `on conflict do nothing` on target able provided you have primary keys defined.

Comment: What about the actual values I need to update?

Comment: assuming two rows with same value have same primary key -- natural key as primary key. Keys can be based on multiple columns. Sample data would be helpful.

Comment: added some example data.

Comment: from what i understand, you would like to only update some fields are changed. unfortunately, that is not quite possible since postgres changes entire tuple/row for every updates. You might want to break main table to smaller tables with subset of fields for what you are trying to achieve.